# Okhttp JSON data parsing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

currently working on an Android App and I'm supposed to send JSON data to a server and receive back a response, but the server doesn't recognize the data frame as a JSON type it still shows its content but replies with a 404 code
here's the code I used :

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        try{
            jsonObj.put("imei",number);
            jsonObj.put("longitude", number);
            jsonObj.put("latitude", number);
            jsonObj.put("speed", number);
            jsonObj.put("battery", number);
            jsonObj.put("date", date);
            jsonObj.put("error", number);
            jsonObj.put("acceleroVal", number);
            jsonObj.put("apn", string);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String json = jsonObj.toString();
        RequestBody.create(json, MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://xxxx.com:2000/api/xxx")
                .put(formBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                }
```

any help is appreciated, feel free to adjust the code.

Comment: 404 means page not found, which means the url is wrong .can you use debug pointers and debug that area and see if the code moves and check where it stops to identify the bug.

and your url is missing "https" is it correct?

Comment: thanks for the reply, the whole code is normally correct, the problem is with the JSON format that isn't recognized by the server, that's why I'm looking for any alternatives